# Microsoft Edge forcing HTTPS and refusing a self-signed certificate

Tags: http, iis, microsoft-edge, hsts

Doing dev work on several sites on my local (Windows 10) PC when out of the blue this morning one site refuses to load in Microsoft Edge (Version 89.0.774.45 (Official build) (64-bit)).  Other local sites are working fine.

I removed the redirect to SSL from web.config and issued a fresh self-signed certificate:  NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID - You can't visit local-prodject.mydomain.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

There is no HSTS in web.config.  I removed the HTTPS redirect from web.config and it's still trying to force HTTPS.  I've done the edge://net-internals/#hsts to delete for local-prodject.mydomain.com and localhost, no change.

I'd prefer to have self-signed working as it was yesterday, and on other sites on my local PC so when they get pushed to a production environment they're ready to go.

I should also note that Chrome and Firefox (Dev and regular) work fine.

Comment: Have you followed the steps like [this article](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/) to delete HSTS settings? Have you specified the proper subdomain when delete? The HSTS settings for subdomains may be different. I suggest that you can clear Edge cache and history to try again. You can also try in inprivate window to see if the issue still exists.

Comment: Yes, I've cleared HSTS and it seems to help for a short while.  I've resorted to typing "thisisnotsafe" in the browser window in Edge and Chrome now to get to any of my local dev sites.

Comment: It seems that you have found a workaround for the issue. You can put it as an answer which can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Chrome, Opera, and Edge have a safe word you can use to bypass this SSL issue for local development. Click anywhere within the browser window and type:  `thisisunsafe`

Comment: will this add the exception permanently ?

Comment: No the exception is not permanent.

Comment: Edge will remember it in a normal window, then it will have effect with InPrivate windows as well.

Comment: This UX make it feel like [Hackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackers_(film))

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: OMG THANK YOU you saved my server.. I (like a dumbass) changed the plesk certificate to a scuffed one and could not use plesk any more to change it back